# Get the top ten equipment from suffixed tables

Tags: php, mysql

I've been developing an application that show what are the top equipment that has problems in the system. For that I´ve create a tables like:

```
---------------------      ---------------------
- equipments_201404 -      - equipments_201405 -
---------------------      ---------------------
- id                -      - id                -
- equipName         -      - equipName         -
- dateTime          -      - dateTime          -
- ...               -      - ...               -
---------------------      ---------------------
```

This kind of separation has to be with the amount of data that has to be storage. Because that, I wondering if there is a way to obtain the top ten equipment in a query or through PHP.

Comment: Are you sure? Have you looked at partitioning? (Although frankly I'd be concerned if there really was so much problematic equipment in your 'system'). Either way, I am 99% certain that you do NOT want to create a new table each month!

Comment: Yes, I need this kind of separation because I had this kind of issue. When I refer to problems I am referring here to alerts and alarms that these devices may have.

Comment: But why is partitioning inappropriate?

Comment: What I've been reading so far it's partitioning it's great for this kind of problems. But I'm still have a doubt that it's: If I've perform a partitioning by month what would happen the next year in terms of date? It would create another twelves partitions? It would "drop" the partitions or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have less than approximately one hundred thousand trouble reports (entries in your `equipments_*` tables per month, than splitting the records into separate tables by month, or partititioning the tables, is definitely a bad idea.  MySQL does just fine at handling tables containing dozens of millions of rows. Just fine. Seriously.

There are tens of thousands of successful applications in the world on modestly sized MySQL servers handling data sets of this size.

On the other hand, systems that employ partitioning require constant maintenance.

If your experience is to the contrary, it's because you haven't figured out how to use indexing and querying correctly.  We can't tell from your question what kind of queries you are running in routine production, so it's not possible to give you clear advice about indexing. That being said, I guess it makes sense to put an index on `(dateTime,id)`.

If you had one table rather than one per month as I suggest, you could do this to get your top ten equipment failures.

```
 SELECT equipName
   FROM equipments
  GROUP BY equipName
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
  LIMIT 10
```

If you wanted the top ten failures for the 6 month period ending at the present time, you could use this query.

```
 SELECT equipName
   FROM equipments
  WHERE dateTime >= NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH 
  GROUP BY equipName
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
  LIMIT 10
```

This query would be made very efficient by a compound index on `(dateTime, equipName)` even for a dataset containing millions of rows spanning decades of time.

As it is, you have split your data into monthly tables. Here's how you can deal with that.  First: use a sequence of `UNION ALL` operations to create a virtual table containing all the data. If all your monthly tables have the same columns in the same order, that's pretty easy if a little boring.

```
SELECT * FROM equipments_201404 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM equipments_201403 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM equipments_201402 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM equipments_201401 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM equipments_201312 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM equipments_201311 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM equipments_201310 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM equipments_201309 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM equipments_201308 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM equipments_201307 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM equipments_201306 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM equipments_201305 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM equipments_201304   /* etc etc you get the idea */
```

If you issue this query you'll get all your records as if they were in one table. Then you can use that as a subquery in the query shown above, as follows.

```
 SELECT equipName
   FROM (
          SELECT * FROM equipments_201404 UNION ALL
          SELECT * FROM equipments_201403 UNION ALL
          SELECT * FROM equipments_201402 UNION ALL
          SELECT * FROM equipments_201401 UNION ALL
          SELECT * FROM equipments_201312 UNION ALL
          SELECT * FROM equipments_201311 UNION ALL
          SELECT * FROM equipments_201310 UNION ALL
          SELECT * FROM equipments_201309 UNION ALL
          SELECT * FROM equipments_201308 UNION ALL
          SELECT * FROM equipments_201307 UNION ALL
          SELECT * FROM equipments_201306 UNION ALL
          SELECT * FROM equipments_201305 UNION ALL
          SELECT * FROM equipments_201304   /* etc etc you get the idea */
        ) AS equipments
  WHERE dateTime >= NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH 
  GROUP BY equipName
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
  LIMIT 10
```

This lets you fake your main summary query into thinking it has one set of uniform data to process.  Of course, indexes won't help much here.

Obviously, I have included too many monthly tables in the six-month query. You can fix that. But you'll need to fix it every month.